# remove decimal places in strings ids using awk

Tags: awk

I want to remove the decimal places in strings from a list of identifiers:

```
ENSG00000166224.12
ENSG00000102897.5
ENSG00000168496.3
ENSG00000010295.15
ENSG00000147533.12
ENSG00000119242.4
```

My desired output will be

```
ENSG00000166224
ENSG00000102897
ENSG00000168496
ENSG00000010295
ENSG00000147533
ENSG00000119242
```

I would like to do it with awk, I have been playing with `printf` but with no success.

UPDATE:

The awk answer setting the field separator to `.` works well in files with only one column, but what if the file is composed of different columns (strings and float numbers)?
Here is an example:

```
ENSG00000166224.12  0.0730716237772557  -0.147970450702234
ENSG00000102897.5   0.156405616866614   -0.0398488625782745
ENSG00000168496.3   -0.110396121325736  -0.0147093758392248
```

How can I remove only the decimal places in the first field?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the field separator to the dot and print the first element:

```
$ awk -F. '{print $1}' file
ENSG00000166224
ENSG00000102897
ENSG00000168496
ENSG00000010295
ENSG00000147533
ENSG00000119242
```

In `sed` you would say `sed 's/\.[^\.]*$//' file`, which will catch everything from the last dot on and remove it.

You would be able to do it with `printf` if it just was a number. Then, you would use something to not print the decimal places. However, since it is an alphanumeric string it is best to handle it as a string.

---

#### Update

Use `gsub` to replace everything from `.` in the first field:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/\..*$/,"",$1)}1' a
ENSG00000166224 0.0730716237772557 -0.147970450702234
ENSG00000102897 0.156405616866614 -0.0398488625782745
ENSG00000168496 -0.110396121325736 -0.0147093758392248
```

Comment: thanks @fedorqui, I will give you the right answer because of the different solutions,

Comment: yep, `awk -F. '{print $1}'` is a muck more elegant way. I'm trying to post the same answer at very first but the f**** capatcha delayed me from posting.

Comment: what about if the file has two another fields and both fields have float numbers?, then the field separator won't work, is there any way to condition the separator to a field?

Comment: @user2380782 not sure if I understand what you mean. Could you post some sample example?

Comment: for example a file with this `ENSG00000166224.12 0.0730716237772557 -0.147970450702234
ENSG00000102897.5 0.156405616866614 -0.0398488625782745
ENSG00000168496.3 -0.110396121325736 -0.0147093758392248`, I would be intersted in only removing decimals from the first field (ENSG....), the field with the string

Comment: @user2380782 please update the question and show input and desired output, since now it is hard to guess what are lines and what are columns.

Answer (score 1):

use sub function also.

```
awk '{sub(/\..*/, "")}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cut`:

```
$ cut -d. -f1 file
ENSG00000166224
ENSG00000102897
ENSG00000168496
ENSG00000010295
ENSG00000147533
ENSG00000119242
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution in perl

`perl -pne 's/\..*$//' file.txt`

This eventually remove everything after the decimal point.